# Authenticating Desktop Application(Electron) with API(symfony)

Tags: api, symfony, security, authentication, electron

I am currently working on a desktop application, written in Electron, which is supposed to authenticate itself to an API server that I am currently providing with Symfony. Now I am wondering how I should design the authentication. At first I thought of a simple login form in the app, which is then sent by post to the server and, if the authentication is successful, the server sends back an API key that authenticates the app for all API calls (valid for x days). Now, however, I don't think that this would be the most elegant and, above all, the safest variant. Then I thought about equipping the server with private and public keys and having the app generate the same so that communication is encrypted. Now I also think that this may have been thought too far. Do you have a few approaches on how I can make this communication and authentification safe and efficient, since the app is only intended as a frontend that communicates with the server via API calls. So the App will have to make a lots of calls.

Thanks in advance

Comment: JSON Web Tokens (JWT) are your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps I have a couple of easily runnable Electron apps that use OAuth 2.x / JWTs and may give you some ideas for your own solution:

- [Initial Sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/11/desktop-apps-overview/)

Maybe get one or both apps running locally, then feel free to post any follow up questions ...